# PySpark: Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o27.awaitTermination

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-kafka

I am trying to connect to Kafka producer using `pyspark`. Using a console producer to produce the data.

Below is the code.

```
import findspark
findspark.init('D:\spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7')
import os
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages org.apache.spark:spark- 
streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.0.2 pyspark-shell'

import sys
import time
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils

if __name__ == "__main__":
n_secs = 1
topic = ["streamtest1"]

## spark config
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("KafkaStreamTest").setMaster("local[2]")

# spark context creation
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
print(sc)
sc.setLogLevel("WARN")

# create streaming context
ssc = StreamingContext(sc,n_secs)

#kafka direct stream to connect to kafka broker
kafkastream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc,topic, 
{'bootstrap.servers':'localhost:9092',
                                        'group.id':'test123',

                         'fetch.message.max.bytes':'15728640'})
print(kafkastream)

#map the Dstream data to lines
lines = kafkastream.map(lambda x : x[1])

words = lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" "))
pairs=words.map(lambda word:(word,1))
counts = pairs.reduceByKey(lambda a,b: a+b)
counts.pprint()

# starts the streaming context
ssc.start()
time.sleep(60)
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

And below is the error:

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o27.awaitTermination.
>   : org.apache.spark.SparkException: An exception was raised by Python:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: What is your spark version?

Comment: @AliAzG spark version is 2.4.0

Comment: It seems some version issues. try installing version 2.3 and run your code on this version.

Comment: any one solved the issue

Comment: I have the same issue! not fixing it yet!